# MySQL / MariaDB, проблема сортировкой

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

После обновления версии MariaDB перестал корректно работать скрипт сортировки элементов:

```
$this->db->query("
    SET @v:=0;
    UPDATE `users` AS `c1`
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `id`, (@v:=@v+2) AS `ord2`, `name`, `parent` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `parent`='0' ORDER BY `ord` ASC) AS `c2`
    ON `c1`.`id` = `c2`.`id`
    SET `c1`.`ord` = `c2`.`ord2`
    WHERE `c1`.`parent` = '0'
");
```

Скрипт применяется в частности к таблице users, изначально отсортированной по полю `ord`:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord | name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   5 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   7 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   9 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

Я плохо знаю возможности SQL, и после долгих поисков и экспериментов я, как мне кажется, обнаружил проблему. В пятой версии MariaDB запрос

```
SELECT `id`, (@v:=@v+2) AS `ord2`, `name`, `parent` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `parent`='0' ORDER BY `ord` ASC;
```

дает результат, сохраняющий исходный порядок записей:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord2| name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   4 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   6 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   8 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

В версии 10.6.3, которую я установил, порядок нарушается:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord2| name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   4 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   8 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   6 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

Я пробовал менять сортировку в запросе, ORDER BY `ord` на ORDER BY `name` и ORDER BY `id`, но результат – тот же. Как будто, несмотря на указание, заполняемый четными числами столбец `ord2` всегда выстраивается по возрастанию `id`.

Как мне изменить или переписать запрос, чтобы восстановить работу скрипта?

Comment: У вас переменная колонка внутри SELECT называется ord2, а упорядочивать вы пытаетесь по ord, которая находится в запросе выше - получается путаница.

Comment: Колонка `ord` присутствует в изначальной таблице `users`, из которой и делается SELECT. Выражением (@v:=@v+2) AS `ord2` добавляется новая колонка, заполненная четными числами: 2, 4, 6 и т.п. Последовательность присвоения этих чисел должна соответствовать порядку элементов в колонке `ord`, для этого и нужна сортировка по ней. Для наглядности колонку `ord` можно включить в условие SELECT, но результат, к сожалению, не поменяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В последних версиях MariaDB вы можете использовать оконную функцию row_number следующим образом:

```
select 
    id,
    (row_number() over (order by ord))*2 ard2,
    name,
    parent
from tbl;
```

[MariaDB query test here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=cdad57b0223a0e7a6a916f36e331ef2d&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)